# set OnClickListener in while loop?

Tags: java, android, while-loop, textview, android-linearlayout

I tried to setup a onClickListner in a while loop like this:

```
    View inflaterLayout;
    LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);      
    while (counter < 5) {
        inflaterLayout = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.newplayerlayout, null);
        myLayout.addView(inflaterLayout); 
        Button testButton = (Button) myLayout.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        testButton.setId(testButtonArray[counter]);
        ((TextView) myLayout.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setId(testTextArray[counter]);
        testButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ((TextView) findViewById(testTextArray[counter])).setText("Hi!");

            }
        });
        counter++;
    }
```

And what I thought it would do is when you click any one of the testButton's it would change the TextView next to it! But only the first button thats inflated works! Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Basically what I'm trying to accomplish is, I'm inflating a layout that has a Plus Button, Minus Button and a Text View, so I want to be able to setup one onClickListener that will add and subtract from the text view without having to setup a million separate onClickListeners!

Comment: i think you should save the button refrence in array. and then set onClicklistener outside the loop.

Comment: I tried that, I just put it all in a loop so everyone knew what I was trying to accomplish.

Comment: I updated my answer from your new description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ((TextView) findViewById(testTextArray[counter])).setText("Hi!");
    }
```

The code inside the onClick function is run when the button *is clicked*. It does not *remember* the values of the variables during each iteration of the loop, simply because it is in a different scope.

**Update**

The following code only uses one OnClickListener to increment or decrement the value of each corresponding TextView. You should be able to easily adapt this to your layout inflater with a better looking layout.

```
public class Example extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                TextView text = (TextView) view.getTag();

                if(((Button) view).getText().equals("+"))
                    text.setText(Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString()) + 1 + "");
                else
                    text.setText(Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString()) - 1 + "");
            }
        };

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            LinearLayout line = new LinearLayout(this);
            line.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            TextView text = new TextView(this);
            text.setText(i + "");
            line.addView(text);

            Button plus = new Button(this);
            plus.setTag(text);
            plus.setText("+");
            plus.setOnClickListener(listener);
            line.addView(plus);

            Button minus = new Button(this);
            minus.setTag(text);
            minus.setText("-");
            minus.setOnClickListener(listener);
            line.addView(minus);

            layout.addView(line);
        }

        setContentView(layout);
    }
}
```

**Addition from comment**

I am going to assume that in your newplayerlayout.xml you have two Buttons (with the ids: "plus" and "minus") and a TextView (with the id "text"). Perhaps you would implement the scheme like this:

```
OnClickListener mListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        TextView text = (TextView) view.getTag();

        if(((Button) view).getText().equals("+"))
            text.setText(Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString()) + 1 + "");
        else
            text.setText(Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString()) - 1 + "");
    }
};
...


while (counter < 5) {
    inflaterLayout = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.newplayerlayout, null);
    myLayout.addView(inflaterLayout);

    TextView inflatedText = (TextView) inflaterLayout.findViewById(R.id.text);
    Button testButton = (Button) inflaterLayout.findViewById(R.id.plus);
    testButton.setTag(inflatedText);
    testButton.setText("+");
    testButton.setOnClickListener(mListener);

    testButton = (Button) inflaterLayout.findViewById(R.id.minus);
    testButton.setTag(inflatedText);
    testButton.setText("-");
    testButton.setOnClickListener(mListener);

    counter++;
}
```

Comment: How would I do that except with my layout inflater? Cause making 3 switch statements with 10+ buttons each isn't really fun.

Comment: Before the way I would save the values for each textview was to assign a variable to each one manually, then save it to sharedpreferences, how do you recommend I do it now?

Comment: Well a Tag is just an Object. You can simply create a custom Object that holds a reference to the TextView and a reference to your SharedPreference variable. If that doesn't help please post a new question with the relevant code and any logcat errors, I'll be glad to help but I need more detail.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
 View inflaterLayout;
    LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);      
    while (counter < 5) {
        inflaterLayout = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.newplayerlayout, null);
        myLayout.addView(inflaterLayout); 
        Button testButton = (Button) myLayout.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        testButton.setId(testButtonArray[counter]);
        ((TextView) myLayout.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setId(testTextArray[counter]);

        testButton.setOnClickListener(btnhandler); // Click Listener here
        counter++;
    }
```

Create Button ClickListener outside while loop as:

```
View.OnClickListener btnhandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {

switch (v.getId()) {
  case testTextArray[0]:
    ((TextView) findViewById(testTextArray[0])).setText("Button One");
    break;
  case testTextArray[1]:
   ((TextView) findViewById(testTextArray[1])).setText("Button Two");
    break;
    .....
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: I would use a `switch` instead of chained `else if` statements

Answer (score 0):

By the code testButton.setOnClickListener() you register a class to execute its onClick() method when button is clicked. So every time a new anonymous class is registered in while loop and when u click on button last registered classe's onClick() method will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

```
View inflaterLayout;
LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);      
while (counter < 5) {
    inflaterLayout = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.newplayerlayout, null);
    myLayout.addView(inflaterLayout); 
    Button testButton = (Button) myLayout.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    testButton.setId(testButtonArray[counter]);
    ((TextView) myLayout.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setId(testTextArray[counter]);
    testButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        int select = counter;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((TextView) findViewById(testTextArray[select])).setText("Hi!");
        }
    });
    counter++;
}
```